# Gradle error. Mixing libraries have to be the same version

Tags: android, gradle

Hopefully someone will be able to help me with this. Somehow I can't resolve this problem. Long story short, I always have this error. Don't know what to do.

[The error in cause:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BGqo2.png)

It all started when I added "Glide" to the project. 
Here's the link to "Glide"in case this helps with something.

https://github.com/bumptech/glide

This is my Gradle project:(Module:app)

```
android {
compileSdkVersion 26
defaultConfig {

    applicationId "******"
    minSdkVersion 19
    targetSdkVersion 26
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"

    dataBinding {
        enabled = true
    }


}
buildTypes {
    release {

        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
```

}

```
dependencies {
implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.6.1'
annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.6.1'
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:support-compat:26.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:animated-vector-drawable:26.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:11.0.4'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:11.0.4'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'
```

`}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'`

And this is my gradle project:

```
buildscript {

repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()


}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1'



    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.1.0'
}
```

}

```
allprojects {
repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()
    mavenCentral()

}
```

}

```
task clean(type: Delete) {
delete rootProject.buildDir
```

}

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The version of glide you use depends on version 27.0.2 of the support library.

You could use an older version of glide, or update the support libraries in your project to 27.0.2.

Alternatively, you can add a resolution strategy to the main build.gradle. Although this could cause issues with glide if glide uses methods only available in 27.0.2.

```
allprojects {
  configurations.all {
    resolutionStrategy {
        force 'com.android.support:support-compat:27.0.2'
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! You are awesome!